# .htaccess doesn't ask me for password

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm trying to protect a directory adding a .htaccess and a .htpasswd but instead asking me for password, it goes to the home page of my site directly.

My .htaccess is being read (put some garbage in it and I got 500 error).

Here's my .htaccess :

```
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/backoffice_mollanger/app/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

And my .htpasswd

```
Admin:gl0IiOirI2n6M
```

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code basically means that there's been an error and you need to check the server log to find out which one.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. Then, i do not have 500 error. Just saying that my .htaccess is being read (because a lot of people have trouble with this problem) because I tested it : I put some garbage in it and I got 500 error which means my file is being read.

Comment: Ah, sorry... Well, your code works for me as-is. Is it possible that's not asking for a password because you already typed it when testing? There's normally no way to "log out" unless you close the browser.

Comment: Clear cache and restart browser. Problem is still here.

Comment: [Here are some readings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/auth.html)

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the speech marks you have around the .htpasswd location, they should not be there. If that does not help then try using this, you can specify the directory you want to protect by stating the file name in replace of example:

```
<Files /example>
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/backoffice_mollanger/app/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Comment: Oh ! I have forgotten dat speech marks. Mistakes were made. Should be very tired this morning to do that :). Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem @RomainBouvet, glad I could help! The amount of times I've made silly mistakes like that lol.